# socket.in().emit() not working as expected in Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("initiateMatch", async (name) => {
    console.log(roomPool);
    let emptyRoomData = searchForEmptyRooms(roomPool);
    if (emptyRoomData.foundEmptyRoom) {
      //create room with player name
      let emptyRoomName = roomPool[emptyRoomData.emptyRoomIndex];
      socket.join(emptyRoomName);
      roomPool[emptyRoomData.emptyRoomIndex].push(name);
      let opponentName = roomPool[emptyRoomData.emptyRoomIndex].filter(
        (player) => player !== name
      )[0];
      console.log(name, opponentName);
      console.log(roomPool[emptyRoomData.emptyRoomIndex][0] + "is the Room Name");
      console.log(searchRoom(roomPool, roomPool[emptyRoomData.emptyRoomIndex]));
      io.in(roomPool[emptyRoomData.emptyRoomIndex][0]).emit("showBoard", name, opponentName);
    } else {
      //no room is empty, create a room with player name
      socket.join(name);
      io.to(name).emit("insufficientPlayers");
      roomPool.push([name]);
    }
  });
});
```

I have an event emitted from the client side to initiateMatch and a condition to check if any room is empty i.e. it has less than 2 players, and put the client into the room. But the io.on().emit() is not working as expected(it should emit to all the users in the room).

I have tried checking everything :

1. The room name returned is correct
2. The opponent and my name is correct.
3. The searchRoom function is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This looks strange:

```
let emptyRoomName = roomPool[emptyRoomData.emptyRoomIndex];
socket.join(emptyRoomName);
roomPool[emptyRoomData.emptyRoomIndex].push(name);
```

On the first line, `roomPool[emptyRoomData.emptyRoomIndex]` is (presumably) a string containing the room name, but on the third line it's being used as an array that you push the player name in to.

Should the first line perhaps be this?

```
let emptyRoomName = roomPool[emptyRoomData.emptyRoomIndex][0];
```

Comment: It returns an array which contains the name of the players.

Comment: And you can pass arrays into `socket.join()`?

Comment: Even after passing the string it is not working.